# Look up the user with bearer token with Openiddict Core

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I am currently using Openiddict, Identity and Entity Framework to manage my users and assign `Bearer` tokens to users to protect my API.

My infrastructure is currently using ASP.NET Core Web API in the back end and a separate React application in the front end.  The React application makes HTTP calls to my API to retrieve it's data.  There is no server side HTML rendering at all in the back end.

Everything works as I need it to for the most part.  I can register users and retrieve tokens from the API.  These tokens are included in my HTTP call in the `Authorization` header.  My `AuthorizationController` uses this: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/PasswordFlow/AuthorizationServer/Controllers/AuthorizationController.cs with a few minor tweaks.  My `Startup.cs` also uses almost exactly this https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/PasswordFlow/AuthorizationServer/Startup.cs

In some instances, I need to make API calls to the endpoints that are specific to the user.  For instance, if I need to know if a user has voted on a comment or not.  Instead of passing along the users `ID` in a query string to get the user details, I would like to use the `Bearer` token I received that they use to make the API call for that endpoint.  I am not sure how to do this though.

In some research I have done it looks like some samples use ASP.NET Core MVC as opposed to the API to retrieve the user with the `User` variable as seen here https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/PasswordFlow/AuthorizationServer/Controllers/ResourceController.cs#L20-L31 however this seems not to apply to my infrastructure.

My question is how do I look up a user based on the `Bearer` token passed to the API to look up a users details from my database?  I am assuming that all of the tokens passed out by the API are assigned to that specific user, right?  If that's the case it should be easy to look them up based on the `Bearer` token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is: How with Openiddict can you look up a user based on the token that was assigned to them for API calls? I need to get the user details before anything else can be done with the application first. Is there something baked internally or do I have to write my own support for this?

When you create an `AuthenticationTicket` in your authorization controller (which is later used by OpenIddict to generate an access token), you have to add a `sub` claim that corresponds to the subject/entity represented by the access token.

Assuming you use the user identifier as the `sub` claim, you can easily extract it from your API endpoints using `User.FindFirst(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject)?.Value` and use it to make your DB lookup.

Comment: I see.  I am sort of new to the whole sub claims aspect of this.  Is there an example somewhere of this use case somewhere I could look at?

Comment: @Sethen if you use Identity, you can take a look at this API controller demo, in the openiddict-samples repo: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/PasswordFlow/AuthorizationServer/Controllers/ResourceController.cs#L20-L31.

Comment: I am little confused because that's how I am doing my look up now.  I am interested in looking up based on the auth token and not the user name directly.  What you linked is exactly how I would look up based on a username.

Comment: Also, where are these tokens stored in the database when they are issued?  Or are they not stored anywhere?

Comment: By default access tokens are not stored in the database for performance. They are self-contained and the only way to find the associated user is to use the `sub` claim (not sure why you can't use it, TBH). If you want to store access tokens in the database, use `options.UseReferenceTokens()`, create a new confidential client application and use the aspnet-contrib introspection middleware. I don't recommend it tho', unless you need things like immediate access token revocation.

Comment: Okay.  I have no issue trying to create a claim but what you pointed to in your comment doesn't seem like it answers my question.

Comment: Also, if access tokens are self contained -- how do you destroy them if they are linked to a user?

Comment: I am not using MVC either, I am using ASP.NET Core API to generate tickets.  I believe your answer for `User.FindFirst` is more specific to me if I am using MVC rather than the API in ASP.NET Core.  None of my HTML is rendered server side.  I simply make REST calls.

Comment: Your question was `How with Openiddict can you look up a user based on the token that was assigned to them for API calls?` and the standard answer for all claim-based infrastructures (and not just apps that use OpenIddict) is to read the token, extract the user identifier claim and use it to retrieve the user from the database. If that doesn't answer your question, I suggest you edit it to clearly mention what you're looking for.

Comment: I am confused on your comment though.  You just linked to a sample of looking up a user with the user manager.  I am curious how that relates to the question.  I am not asking to be difficult, I am asking because I don’t understand how it answers the question in reading the token.

Comment: Oh, I see.  The ‘User’ that’s passed there is used to look up the user.  Is this available if I am not using MVC though or does that get set somewhere else?

Comment: Well, repeating that you're confused doesn't help answer question. It's possible that I misunderstood your question and that's why I asked you to rephrase it/add more details about what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: I have completely edited my question to be more specific to what I am trying to accomplish.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't know what's the framework you're using so it's hard to give you the exact syntax. Are you using NancyFX? Is your API based on low-level ASP.NET Core middleware?

Comment: Oh, I updated my question again with my `Startup.cs` file, which comes almost straight out of the openiddict sample.  I am not using NancyFX, I am just using ASP.NET Core middleware.

Comment: Thing is the `Startup.cs` file you're referring to doesn't use custom middleware for the API endpoints but good old ASP.NET Core controllers (the `ResourceController` I mentioned earlier is an API controller). Unfortunately, my answer will remain the same. Not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: If you already have an access token issued by OpenIddict, it necessarily contains the `sub` claim, which is the only mandatory claim (if you don't add it, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException` when calling `SignIn`).

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Is the `User` variable always available in that context in your answer?

Comment: lol, why don't you just try the snippet? `User` is a property exposed by `ControllerBase`, which is a core MVC thing, so yes. And if you're outside an MVC controller, you can still access it via `HttpContext.User`.

Comment: I did try the snippet and the `User` was unavailable in this instance.  I was just curious if it was supposed to always be available or not or if there was some special namespace I had to use to access it.

Comment: Your solution worked, I think I had a misunderstanding of some things.  I marked it as the correct answer.